# OpenVBX block caller id patterns

Tags: php, twilio

We are getting automated calls coming to twillio. We do have openvbx installed. I am trying to figure out how I can block calls with incoming DID that have 111, 110, or 101 in the beginning. I know how to input static numbers in openvbx and I can successfully block them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no support for openvbx on here and from twilio. To post a question here on stackoverflow and tag it openvbx it said I needed to have a certain number of points. I am new to this so my account has no points.

Anyways I solved my own question. Here is the explanation to other users looking for a similar solution.

You need to edit plugins/standard/applets/start/twiml.php in your openvbx installation and make it the code below. I hope there is more support out there for openvbx.

```
<?php 
$ci =& get_instance();
$list = AppletInstance::getValue('list');
$direction = isset($_REQUEST['Direction']) ? $_REQUEST['Direction'] : 'inbound';


// block calls
$caller = normalize_phone_to_E164(isset($_REQUEST['From'])? $ci->input->get_post('From') : '');

$response = new TwimlResponse;

// Update this list of numbers

$block_list = array('+112345678910');

//pattern analysis to block DIDs
$patterns = array('111','110','101','+111','+110','+101');
$position = 0;
foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
 if( $position = strpos(' ' . $caller, $pattern)) {
    if( $position == 1 ) $response->reject(array('reason' => 'busy'));

  }

}

if (in_array($caller, $block_list)) {
        $response->reject(array('reason' => 'busy'));

}else{
        $next = AppletInstance::getDropZoneUrl('next');
        if (!empty($next)) {
                $response->redirect($next);
        }
}
$response->respond();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Twilio Customer Support here.

Have you thought about using the Twilio  verb? It will allow you to build a list of numbers you do not wish to receive calls from:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/reject

https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/reject

Regards,
Tom